# How to test only the "key" from .properties file in java using Junit

Tags: java, junit, key, properties-file

I have a class ReadPropertyFile which contains method called getPropertyFor which returns a value for the given key as parameter. The getPropertyFor() method I'm calling from other class with key as input parameter. My contents of the properties filetestConfig.properties(file name) are:
FILE_NAME=D:/Refreshed_data_daily/all_hue_posts_in_excel.xlsx

```
    public class ReadPropertyFile {


    private Properties properties;
    public ReadPropertyFile(String propertyFileName) {

        properties= new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(new FileReader(propertyFileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public String getPropertyFor(String key) {
        return properties.getProperty(key);
    }
}

@Test
public void testFilePathValueInConfigFile(){
    assertEquals(propertyFileObj.getPropertyFor(keyForFilePath), "D:/Refreshed_data_daily/all_hue_posts_in_excel.xlsx");
}
```

The above test case is to check if the value returned by the function is correct. How do I check if the key is correct? What can be the possible test cases to test the key. And I don't want to change my testConfig.properties file for test purpose.
I need help , I'm new to Java Junit testing.

Comment: What exactly do you want check for the key? Whether the key is present in the properties file or not? Or you want to find the key based on the value?

Comment: I want to check if the key is present in the properties file. How do I check it?

Comment: just do assertNotNull(properties.getProperty(FILE_NAME)

Comment: This test will actually check if the value corresponding value to the key FILE_NAME is not null!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test wether a key is present in properties file, the there are 2 ways:

If have specified the dafault values for your properties with some predefined values via properies constructor and if you'll try to get the key and it doesn't exist, you'll get this default value back. In that case, you have to check, if your return is equals to this default value.

But if you didn't provide the default, then you can simply use asserNotNull on it's return value, due to javadoc for Propery#getProperty:

> Searches for the property with the specified key in this property list. If the key is not found in this property list, the default property list, and its defaults, recursively, are then checked. The method returns null if the property is not found.

But in case of unit testing, you have to provide a number of different properties to test all the possible behaviours of your method or class.

Comment: Is 'asserNotNull(propertyFileObj.getPropertyFor(keyForFilePath))' is a valid test case to check if the key is present or not? Or this test case checks if the value corresponding value to the key FILE_NAME is not null! ? I'm getting confused here!!

Comment: Updated the answer. asserNotNull is valid, if you didn't provide a default values. if you provided them, you have to get them from your properties instance an check, wether your returned value equals to default. But anyway, you have to check only your class behavior, if it has some special logic in case, you didn't provide a key, then you have to test it. If you didn't, no reason to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a properties file called myprop.properties:

```
key1=value1
key2=
key3
```

You can write the below 4 tests to check if a property is missing or not. As illustrated in different cases, only key (key4) not inside the properties file will **return null** when you call properties.get("key4"). In the case of key1, it returns value1. In cases of key2 and key3, empty string is returned.

Therefore, to check if a key is present in a properties file, you can use **Assert.assertNull(properties.get(KEY_NAME))**.

```
public class CheckPropertiesTest {
Properties properties = new Properties();

@Before
public void init() throws IOException {
    properties.load(CheckProperties.class.getResourceAsStream("/myprop.properties"));
}

@Test
public void test1() {
    Assert.assertNotNull(properties.get("key1"));
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    Assert.assertNotNull(properties.get("key2"));
}

@Test
public void test3() {
    Assert.assertNotNull(properties.get("key3"));
}

@Test
public void test4() {
    Assert.assertNull(properties.get("key4"));
}
}
```